# ERR! code ELIFECYCLE errno 1 when run the react project

Tags: reactjs

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webapp@0.1.0 start: `rimraf ./build && react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the webapp@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/admin-pc/.npm/_logs/2019-11-08T11_10_32_424Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

uninstalled the nodejs LTS version.
install the nodejs current version in c:/windows/system32

and its working again!!

refer the Link:https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6950